# Data not storing in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I am trying to add some data to a pandas DataFrame in python but for some reason, the code just runs through my method without adding the data.

Printing `log_return` shows values so that DataFrame is not empty.

```
def __init__(self, stocks):
    self.log_return = pd.DataFrame()
    self.simple_return = pd.DataFrame()
    self.annual_return = pd.Series()
    self.covariance = pd.DataFrame()
    self.correlation = pd.DataFrame()
    self.nstocks = int
    self.portfolio_returns = []
    self.portfolio_volatilities = []
    self.log_return = self.get_log_return()
    self.simple_return = self.get_simple_return()
    self.annual_return = self.get_annual_return()
    self.covariance = self.get_covariance()
    self.correlation = self.get_correlation()
    self.nstocks = len(stocks)

def get_log_return(self):
    self.update_log_return()
    return self.log_return

def get_covariance(self):
    self.update_covariance()
    return self.covariance

def update_covariance(self):
    self.covariance = self.log_return.cov() * 250

def update_log_return(self):
    self.log_return = np.log(self.data / self.data.shift(1))
```

Comment: please add your code as text .

Comment: I have like 2 classes, I will attach the important parts and then if it is not enough I will send it all.

Comment: I just realized that when I call the get_covariance() method in the same class file it works but when I want to use it outside the class it doesn't work